# how to prepopulate the selected value in Db in a @html.Dropdown in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to pre-populate the selected value stored in the  DB in the Dropdown list in mvc.

> Controller

```
public ActionResult POCallDown(int? skuid)
{
    var supplierlist = db.QuoteMasters.Include(e => e.CommunicationMode).Include(e => e.SKUMaster).Include(e => e.EmployeeMaster).Include(e => e.SupplierMaster).Include(e => e.CreditTerm);
    var SupplierforSKU = (from supplierdetails in supplierlist.ToList()
                                  where skuid.HasValue && skuid.Value == supplierdetails.SKU
                                  select supplierdetails).ToList();

    foreach(var cred in SupplierforSKU)
    { 
        ViewBag.CreditId = new SelectList(db.CreditTerms, "CreditId", "Description",cred.CreditTermId);
    }
    return View(SupplierforSKU);

}
```

> View

```
<table>
<th>Credit</th> 
<tr><td> @Html.DropDownList("CreditId")</td></tr>
</table>
```

I get the first value in the db for all the rows in the view. Please help. I tried using this  [Populate dropdown](http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/populate-selected-item-in-dropdownlist.html)  but it dowsnot give me the desired result.

Comment: Pre-populate the selected value ? You mean what ever value is mapped to this entity must be selected and the rest should appear unselected ?

Comment: yes.. say, if credit term named "abc" with id 1 is saved for a particular record in the db,i want to show "abc" selected in the mvc dropdown in the view and rest of the values visible in clickin the dropdown.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the desired id in `cred.CreditTermId` ? Debug and check.

Comment: yes.. the desired id is retrieved in the controller but the view shows only the first item in the DB in the table,say if "abc" is the first,all the rows in the html table shows "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <table>
     <th>Credit</th> 
       <tr>
         <td> 
            @Html.DropDownList("CreditId", null, "--Select One--", new { @id = "CreditId", @name ="CreditId"})
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```